# ¿Como puedo actualizar un color map de manera rapida en tiempo real en python?

Tags: python-3.x, map, color, real-time

Buenas tengo que hacer un colormap que valla creciendo a medida que va avanzando el tiempo y cree el siguiente codigo pero luego de un par actualizaciones se demora mucho en avanzar,  tambien probe creando un array para luego ir llenandolo de datos, que andaba mas rapido pero me deja todos los puntos dentro de la matriz incial y no avanza. 
¿que podría hacer para que ande mas rapido?
estoy usando python 3.7

```
import numpy as np                  # Cargamos numpy como el alias np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     # Crgagamos matplotlib.pyplot como el alias plt
import matplotlib.colors
import random
from time import time


cc=51
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(0,255)
colors = [[norm(0), "w"],
         [norm(cc), "blue"],
         [norm(cc*2), "green"],
         [norm(cc*3), "yellow"],
         [norm(cc*4), "darkorange"],
         [norm(cc*5), "red"]]

cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", colors)
data=[]
o=0


# Creamos una figura
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.ioff()
#im= ax.imshow(np.random.random((50,50)),cmap)#usarlo con el set array

#plt.xlim([0, 2000])
#plt.ylim([0, 2000])  
# Creamos los arrays dimensionales
x = np.arange(-10, 10, 1)
y = np.arange(-10, 10,1)

# Obtenemos las corrdenadas resultantes de esos arrays
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)


# datos y grafico


def plot(data,cmap):
   # im.set_array(data) #Update la matriz del colormap


    plt.imshow(data,cmap,interpolation='none')

    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()    
    plt.show(block=False)  

def datos(tam):
    wf_data=np.random.rand(tam)   
    return wf_data

while o<100:
    start_time = time()
    print(o)   
    data.append(datos(100))      
    o=o+1 

    plot(data,cmap)
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print("Elapsed time: %0.10f seconds." % elapsed_time)
```